# Java - Writing and appending to text file is causing multiple entries

Tags: java, file-writing

I am making a game. When the game is over, I want to write the score to a text file, on a new line. I have found a way to do this, but It gave me a weird output; when I open my text file after the game has ended, I have loads of duplies, i.e. if my score is 2 and my second score is 3 it should be

```
2
3
```

But my output is like this (Only fragment, I just didn't want to show the 30 or so repeats)

```
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
3
3
3
3
3
3
```

My code is:

```
if(gameover == true) {
        File file  = new File("scoreFile.txt");
            try {
                FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
                PrintWriter printer = new PrintWriter(writer);
                printer.println(points);
                printer.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

If I remove the `true` from my file writer, it only does one entry but obviously I don't want it to be overwritten. I have no idea why this is happening. I have tried to solve it at multiple places. Initially it stood within my paint component but now I have put it in my `actionPerformed()`. However, it should only write when the conditions are met (if play = false and game over = true).

Any ideas? Or any other methods to add to the text while without the filewriter append parameter.

Comment: Change this if(play == false & gameover == true) to  if(play == false && gameover == true)

Comment: Be sure to close your FileWriter

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, even with the two && the output is still the same.

Comment: @NickDechiara i also tried closing both, still the same result.

Comment: The function must be getting called more than once; you could try adding a "scorewritten" boolean that you set to true after writing the score once, and then add && !scorewritten to your conditional. Then, just reset scorewritten to false when you start a new match.

Comment: Ah thanks a lot this did the job, yes it must've been writing to the file after each little action, such as if the paddle moves or the ball moves.

Comment: Note that nowadays writing and reading files is done using Javas new I/O API called **NIO**. It revolves around the classes `Files`, `Paths` and `Path`.